# How can I split a Bash string as separate variables?

Tags: bash, text-processing

I have an example string:

```
echo $ExampleString
"Hello World" var2 var3
```

How can I split the string to be separate variables?

Desired outcome:

```
echo ${ExampleStringArray[0]}
Hello World

echo ${ExampleStringArray[1]}
var2

echo ${ExampleStringArray[2]}
var3
```

Comment: Does the variable contain the literal double quotes around `Hello World`?

Comment: Yes it does, this is the part that made me seek help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `eval` to create an array:

```
eval ExampleStringArray=($ExampleString)
```

Which will create:

```
declare -a ExampleStringArray=([0]="Hello World" [1]="var2" [2]="var3")
```

Although you should be wary if the variable contains any potential commands or special characters.

Comment: So simple and clean. Appreciate the introduction to eval.