# How can I split a string containing a Bash command without expanding parameters?

Tags: bash, command-line, split

I have a single string that contains a shell command line. I need to remove a specific argument from this string (if present), and print the result, while keeping it a valid shell command. How can I accomplish this?

I’ve tried two different approaches:

- `eval args=($cmd)` as shown in [How can I split a Bash string as separate variables?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/564830/3651)
- a `while read arg` loop (*not* `read -r`, which also won’t work!)

But both solutions also perform parameter substitution. That is, if the command is `docker run --name $boxid`, the parameter `$boxid` will be replaced by its value at the point where I’m patching the command. I need to preserve the unexpanded parameter.

To give a more complete example, consider the following command string:

```
docker run -v /foo:/foo:ro --name "$boxid" container bash -c "some shell string"
```

And I might need to get rid of the `-v /foo…` argument, which may be at any arbitrary position (i.e. not necessarily immediately following `docker run`), while preserving all other arguments so that Bash would parse them identically; so all three of the following results would be acceptable:

```
docker run --name "$boxid" container bash -c "some shell string"
docker run --name "$boxid" container bash -c some\ shell\ string
"docker" "run" "--name" "$boxid" "container" "bash" '-c' "some shell string"
```

---

Since this sounds like a wildly misguided request/XY problem, let me give some background:

I’ve got a Bash script that’s part of a larger software (Nextflow), which contains a shell function (`launch`) that runs a command (`docker run …`). The command may contain an argument that I need to remove, because it causes an error in my specific case.<sup>1</sup>

I have no control over this script itself, but the software allows users to inject arbitrary Bash code into the script shortly before the `launch` function is invoked (but after it was defined). So my idea was to inject essentially the following piece of code, which redefines the `launch` function on the fly:

```bsh
eval "$(declare -f launch | sed '/docker run/s/OFFENDING ARGUMENT//')"
```

This works. But unfortunately it isn’t future-proof: small changes to the script might break simple textual substitution. I need to make the patching more robust. And I can’t shell it out to another programming languages since this might be running on a bare-bone machine with only Bash installed.

---

<sup>1</sup> This isn’t a bug in the software — my use-case is slightly outside the software’s specification.